# Missing constant and "const_missing" inside "class << self" definition

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm greatly confused by Ruby's behavior when defining `const_missing` and other class methods inside a `class << self` definition as opposed to using the `def self.foo` syntax.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def foo
      puts MISSING
    end

    def const_missing(name)
      puts "#{name} missing"
    end
  end
end

Foo.foo
```

I mostly use the the `class << self` syntax to define class methods. However, it did not work as expected. `const_missing` is never called. The above results in a NameError.

Defining both methods like this works as expected:

```
def self.foo
  puts MISSING
end

def self.const_missing(name)
  puts "#{name} missing"
end
```

I thought that the `class << self` syntax is just another way to define class methods, but completely equivalent to `def self.foo`? I've tested the above with MRI 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and JRuby 1.5.6. So obviously I'm missing something here?

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`class << self` is not a shortcut to define class methods. This syntax (I don't know the exact naming) opens the eigenclass from a object (in your case, a class). With that you can define methods to the object (not instance methods). But when you call a constant into the eigenclass, you are calling a constant from the eigenclass, not from the class. In this case you have to define a class method on the eigenclass to the `const_missing`, two ways to do that:

```
class Test
  class << self
    def foo
      p MISSING
    end

    # First way: (syntax sugar for the second way)
    def self.const_missing(name)
      name
    end

    # Second way:
    class << self # eigenclass of the eigenclass of the class
      def const_missing(name)
        name
      end
    end

  end
end

Test.foo #=> :MISSING
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, LBg. I knew that `class << self` opens up the eigenclass of a class. But since class methods are just instance methods of the eigenclass I thought it would work this way. It makes perfectly sense, however, that a constant referred to from the eigenclass is not the same as a constant referred to from the class itself. Sometimes this whole thing makes my head spin :)